# Terms of a converginging sequence eventually exceed half of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

$a_n$ is a sequence with limit $L$. In other words, $\forall \varepsilon > 0:\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \ge N: |a_{n} - L | < \varepsilon$

In proof of theorem 3.8c, the [book](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/RealAnalysis/) says it is possible to choose $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m > M: |a_m| > |L| / 2$.

I don't get how to prove this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true only if $L \neq 0$ (otherwise take $a_n = L = 0$).

First assume $L > 0$ and take $\varepsilon = \frac{L}{2}$. Then $\exists M$ such that $\forall n > M\colon |a_n - L| < \frac{L}{2}$. It implies $L - a_n < \frac{L}{2}$, so $a_n > L - \frac{L}{2} = \frac{L}{2}$.

For $L < 0$ either repeat almost the same reasoning, or consider sequence $-a_n$.

Comment: Does that step in the prove also works for $L = 0$? If $L$ is 0, then $\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \ge N : |a_n| < \epsilon$. That means for each epsilon, there is an $N$ that works. I choose the greatest $N$ among all these $N$. Then, $ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \forall n \ge N : |a_n| < \epsilon$. That means $ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} :  \forall n \ge N : |a_n| = 0$ by exerciese 2.12.

Comment: It doesn't work for $L = 0$ as we can't choose $\varepsilon = \frac{L}{2}$. Also in your third sentences you switched order of quantifiers over $N$ and $\varepsilon$, and you can't do that without justification.

Comment: Because in definition of limits we have $\forall \varepsilon > 0$. So we can't substitute $\varepsilon = 0$. More exactly (book doesn't use letter $L$ at all in this part), if $B = 0$ we can't achieve $|b_n - B| < B^2 \varepsilon / 2$.

Comment: But depending of $\varepsilon$ we can get different $N$, and it's entirely possible (and usual case) that we can't choose single $N$ for all $\varepsilon$, as $N$ growth infinitely when $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Counter example: a sequence where all terms are 0. So if $L = 0$, the statement in my question is false. Thanks for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, if this isn't true, then your sequence $a_n$ can't get close to its supposed limit $L$.

Formally, after setting $\epsilon = |L|/2$, we can find $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $m > M$,
$$|a_m - L| <\epsilon = |L|/2$$
and so
$$L -|L|/2  < a_m < |L|/2 + L.$$
Now check what happens when $L >0$ or $L<0$. Hope this helps!